# StringBuilder seems to be out of capacity

Tags: android, stringbuilder

my app retrieves VCards as Strings and puts all together to a big string via StringBuilder

```
public String getVcardStrings() throws Exception {
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) ;
    do {
        String s = getVCardStringFromContact(cursor);
        L.d("VCARD", s);
        builder.append(s);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    cursor.close();

    L.d("VCARD", "Output: \n" + builder.toString());
    return builder.toString();
}
```

The output of each getVCardAsString() call is correct. It contains all data. but calling builder.toString() onlly returns the vcard data of 1,5 Contacts, which is about 4kb of text data and the rest is simply missing!

There is no exception and I´ve read that StringBuilders capacity theoretically reaches up to 4GB. Now my question is, what is happening here?

Comment: What is the output of the 2 log lines you have in there?  What are you ultimately trying to do with the returned string values?

Comment: It actually returns part of string? Or you mean that log outputs only part? second case is normal )

Comment: It not just only prints 2 log lines, it actually prints about 25 lines, one complete contact and a half one. Could be a logger thing indeed. Changed it now to write immediately to file after reading a contact from database, now this "problem" is obsolete to me. thank you anyway =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is a false positive:

In other words the data is there but is being truncated by logcat.
This observation would seem to be validated by this define:

```
#define LOGGER_ENTRY_MAX_LEN        (4*1024)
```

Which is bang-on 4KB and relates directly to what you are experiencing.

Write your output to a file to check if its actually there.

Comment: where do I have to put this line?

Comment: That define is in the Android OS. There is nothing you can do to change it short of building your own ROM. If you want to test this really quickly, output the string to a TextView and see if you get everything you are expecting.